# Chain hitting a scale

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, free-body-diagram

a standard problem in textbooks is to calculate the force of a chain of length $L$ as it hits a scale and has fallen a length $x$. It is found to be $3gMx/L$ by the gravitational force $xmg/L$ and momentum change $2mgx/L$.

However aren’t we missing the acceleration of the chain as well?

In particular, if I want to calculate dp/dt, isn’t there two factors v dm/dt + m dv/dt? We can calculate v dm/dt easily as 2mgx/L using conservation of energy. But why can we neglect the m dv/dt term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it difficult to interpret physically what one is doing when one writes $\frac {d(mv)}{dt}= m\frac{dv}{dt}+v\frac{dm}{dt}$, and I offer this treatment instead...

The length of chain that hits the scales in a small time $\Delta t$ is $v \Delta t = \sqrt{2gx}\ \Delta t$.

The (downward) momentum lost by the chain in time $\Delta t$ is therefore $-\Delta p=\frac ML \sqrt{2gx}\ \Delta t \times \sqrt{2gx}\ \ =\frac ML 2gx\ \Delta t $.

Using Newton's laws II and III, the downward force on the scales due to the changing momentum of the chain is $\frac {\Delta p}{\Delta t}=\frac ML 2gx$.

Adding the weight, $\frac Mlx\ g$, of the length $x$ of chain that, having fallen, is resting on the scales, the total force is $\frac ML 3gx$.

Further thoughts... The 'dynamic' term, $\frac ML 2gx$ can be written as $v\frac{dm}{dt}$. This looks like the second term in $m\frac{dv}{dt}+v\frac{dm}{dt}$, which purports to give the force on a body of changing mass, in this case the part of the chain that is falling. My interpretation, though, is that $v\frac{dm}{dt}$ is simply good old $\mathbf F=m \mathbf a$ applied to a (fixed) mass $dm$ of chain that is changing its velocity from $v$ downwards to zero in a time $dt$. [I suspect that, although $\frac {d(m \mathbf v)}{dt}=m\frac {d\mathbf v)}{dt}+\mathbf v \frac{dm}{dt}$ is mathematically correct, it cannot be used to find the resultant force on a body of changing mass in purely Newtonian Physics, where changing mass implies that the body itself is changing its identity due to loss or gain of matter.]

Comment: I think the use of that first equation is due to the fact that the entire chain does not hit the scale at once, and so there is a rate of mass flow dm/dt, that being each segment of the chain as it hits the scale. The reason why the first part of the equation (with mdv/dt) is not being used is probably because of the fact (as per your analysis) that we are focusing on the speed as the chain hits the scale, which is obviously zero, hence it would not make sense to use that term since dv/dt=0. +1 for a good analysis.

Comment: @Joseph h. Thanks for the upvote. One notes that in the other answer, Eli interprets the $m$ in  $m\frac{dv}{dt}$ as the mass of the chain that has already fallen, and $\frac{dv}{dt}$ as $g$. So $m\frac{dv}{dt}$ is equal to the weight of fallen chain. So Eli gets the right answer, but I don't like, Eli's interpretation of $m\frac{dv}{dt}$ because $m\frac{dv}{dt}+v\frac{dm}{dt}$ is supposed to be representing the force due to the chain striking the scales. If we try to interpret $\frac{dv}{dt}$ as the deceleration as the chain hits the scales, we surely mustn't use  $m$ as coefficient...

Comment: because the deceleration is only local. It's my opinion that for $F=m\frac{dv}{dt}+v\frac{dm}{dt}$ is inapplicable to a body that's changing its mass by gaining or losing matter, but, of course, I haven't shown that this is the case..

Comment: @PhilipWood you think that my answer is wrong or it is just interpretation problem?. why is the result correct?

Comment: @Eli I've tried to explain, in my comment above, why I don't like your putting $\frac{dv}{dt}=g$ in the context of $F=m\frac{dv}{dt}+v\frac{dm}{dt}$, which surely is supposed to give the force due to the chain hitting the scales, and I've also tried to explain why it gives the right answer. The down-vote for your answer was not, though, from me. I didn't vote.

Comment: @PhilipWood I didn’t try to interpret the equation. I just use the mathematical rules, and got the right answer , so why it is correct. I think that must students unterstand it because it is straightforward

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you are right , there is two factors.

the force  F is:

$$F=\frac{dp}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}\,(m\,v)=
v\,\frac {dm}{dt}+m(x)\,\frac{dv}{dt}$$

with
$$v^2=2g x\quad\Rightarrow, 2\,v\,dv=2\,g\,dx
\quad,v\frac{dv}{dt}=g\,v\quad\,\frac{dv}{dt}=g$$

and

$$dm=\frac ML\,dx\quad,\frac {dm}{dt}=\frac ML\,v\\
m(x)=\frac ML\,x$$

you obtain for $~F(x)~$

$$F(x)=\frac{3\,M\,g}{L}\,x\quad ,0\le x\le L$$